# Sending HTTP requests

Tags: http, python-requests

I want to make a bot that would send some post requests and other http requests. I want to ask you what is the easiest language to do this. The language that requires the least of writing, maybe not to install any modules, and also the most simple one.

Answer (score 0):

Python has an awesome module called [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/). A simple post request:

```
import requests

payload = {'key':'value'}
r = requests.post('http://httpbin.org/post', data = payload)
```

> maybe not to install any modules, and also the most simple one.

It's so simple to install a Python module like requests, just this:

```
> pip install requests
```